# Where is the ApiClient method RequestJWTUserToken?

Tags: docusignapi

According to the documentation and GitHub repository for the SDK, ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow and ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey are deprecated and RequestJWTUserToken should be used. I am following the examples, and using the Official NuGet DocuSign 3.0.1.0 package. This method does not appear to exist even in the repository? What is suppose to be used and does anyone have suggestion on how to complete this?

Here is the sample code block I am working with:

```cs
public class DocuSignEmbeddedTest
{
    ...

    public string JWTAuthLogin()
    {
        // we set the api client in global config when we configured the client 
        var apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;

        // Get your app specific Uri generated
        string oauthLoginUrl = GetAuthorizationURLforConsent();

        const string oAuthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";

        var tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(IntegratorKey, UserID, oAuthBasePath, PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES, 1);

        var userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(tokenInfo.access_token);

        var accountId = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in userInfo.Accounts)
        {
            if (item.IsDefault == "true")
            {
                accountId = item.AccountId;
                apiClient = new ApiClient(item.BaseUri + "/restapi");
                break;
            }
        }

        return accountId;
    }

    public string GetAuthorizationURLforConsent()
    {
        // we set the api client in global config when we configured the client 
        var apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;

        // Give consent to your app
        // Adding signature as out scope.
        var scopes = new List<string>
        {
            OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE,
            OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION
        };
        const string redirectUrl = "<url>";

        var oauthLoginUrl = apiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(IntegratorKey, scopes, redirectUrl, OAuth.CODE, "test");

        return oauthLoginUrl.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    public void ConfigureApiClient(string basePath)
    {
        // instantiate a new api client
        var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

        // set client in global config so we don't need to pass it to each API object.
        Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RequestJWTUserToken method accepts private key bytes or stream. Sample code is still using string variable. Please update the sample code to use bytes.

//Private Key Stream - add the stream for your PRIVATE Key here
  private readonly string PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES = "[PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES]";

var tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(IntegratorKey, UserID, oAuthBasePath, PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES, 1);

Answer (score 0):

It is in the current release. See line 990 of [ApiClient.cs](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs)